# elementary topology exercises reference

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Can anyone recommend a good collection of elementary topology exercises? A pdf collection of undergraduate problem sets and homework, or midterm and final exams that I could practice on? Even a webpage would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: See Elementary Topology: Problem textbook

Comment: Take a look at this question of mine, and in particular the answers. The accepted answer has a problem book recommendation. Also Gamelin & Greene have solutions to their problems. And the videos make things quite clear: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953117/reference-request-to-prepare-for-hatchers-algebraic-topology/1037178#1037178

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of exercises is [Topology Without Tears](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~megereli/topbook.pdf), for which I add that is a topology without fears.

Comment: here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60154/topology-without-tears is a review